# R How to effectively change datatype of an entire column from char to numeric/double in R

Tags: r

I've tried couple of ways to change some selected columns of my data set from chr to num, but 2 columns have failed to changed while the remaining 14columns changed effectively.
Viewing the dataset, I noticed that a row across both column has an exponential value in the form of (2.4999999999863576E-2) and (1.6000000000076398E-2) on row 5 of the picture.

Here are the code samples I've tried

```
animals[3:16] <- sapply(animals[3:16], as.numeric)
```

I found that column 12 and 13 refused to change bcos they include an exponent value

and I've also tried this below[image: Screenshot of viewing the animal dataset]:

```
animals <- animals %>%
  mutate(animals[3:16], as.numeric) %>%
  str()
```

I also tried running:
`dput(head(animals, 20))` as suggested in the comment, and the output I got was:

```
structure(list(Class = c(NA, "Total live animals 1/", NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, "Bovine animals, live", NA, NA, NA, NA, "Swine, live", 
NA, NA, NA, "Sheep and goats, live", NA, NA, NA), Source = c(NA, 
NA, "CANADA", "MEXICO", "REST OF WORLD", "WORLD", "Quantity", 
NA, "CANADA", "MEXICO", "WORLD", "Quantity", NA, "CANADA", "WORLD", 
"Quantity", NA, "CANADA", "WORLD", "Quantity"), `1999` = c(NA, 
NA, "876.86900000000003", "292.15800000000002", "0.14799999999991087", 
"1169.175", "6058.3639999999996", NA, "639.02099999999996", "292.12700000000001", 
"931.14700000000005", "1868.85", NA, "216.06399999999999", "216.16399999999999", 
"4136.3490000000002", NA, "5.298", "5.3289999999999997", "53.164999999999999"
), `2000` = c(NA, NA, "995.94500000000005", "405.31099999999998", 
"7.6000000000135515E-2", "1401.3320000000001", "6521.7830000000004", 
NA, "680.55499999999995", "405.291", "1085.846", "2115.8440000000001", 
NA, "290.18599999999998", "290.262", "4352.9790000000003", NA, 
"5.7270000000000003", "5.7469999999999999", "52.96"), `2001` = c(NA, 
NA, "1343.479", "407.90100000000001", "2.6999999999816282E-2", 
"1751.4069999999999", "7758.1139999999996", NA, "966.86", "407.88799999999998", 
"1374.7629999999999", "2353.1260000000002", NA, "344.267", "344.267", 
"5316.26", NA, "8.3849999999999998", "8.4009999999999998", "88.727999999999994"
), `2002` = c(NA, NA, "1394.8150000000001", "300.49599999999998", 
"0.39899999999988722", "1695.71", "8302.9", NA, "1056.4960000000001", 
"300.49599999999998", "1357.0070000000001", "2426.1660000000002", 
NA, "299.505", "299.70100000000002", "5725.6980000000003", NA, 
"12.375999999999999", "12.564", "151.036"), `2003` = c(NA, NA, 
"784.26499999999999", "469.92599999999999", "0.17700000000002092", 
"1254.3679999999999", "9223.2039999999997", NA, "361.27199999999999", 
"469.92599999999999", "831.19899999999996", "1718.5650000000001", 
NA, "389.28", "389.30700000000002", "7429.4080000000004", NA, 
"7.5350000000000001", "7.6840000000000002", "75.230999999999995"
), `2004` = c(NA, NA, "560.14099999999996", "540.99699999999996", 
"0.52899999999999636", "1101.6669999999999", "9866.2780000000002", 
NA, "5.5E-2", "540.97900000000004", "541.03300000000002", "1366.1659999999999", 
NA, "529.35199999999998", "529.86", "8499.9449999999997", NA, 
"0", "0.03", "0.16700000000000001"), `2005` = c(NA, NA, "1134.8900000000001", 
"515.452", "0.29599999999982174", "1650.6379999999999", "9951.94", 
NA, "526.17200000000003", "515.41099999999994", "1041.5830000000001", 
"1818.3969999999999", NA, "580.78899999999999", "580.82899999999995", 
"8131.1589999999997", NA, "7.5999999999999998E-2", "0.20799999999999999", 
"2.3839999999999999"), `2006` = c(NA, NA, "1616.479", "524.24900000000002", 
"0.31999999999970896", "2141.0479999999998", "10985.52", NA, 
"1032.4000000000001", "524.23800000000006", "1556.636", "2301.8040000000001", 
NA, "558.91", "558.91", "8680.5859999999993", NA, "0.40300000000000002", 
"0.41499999999999998", "3.13"), `2007` = c("Million $", NA, "2069.1579999999999", 
"475.42", "0.11099999999987631", "2544.6889999999999", "12419.455", 
NA, "1411.558", "475.42", "1886.9780000000001", "2508.6689999999999", 
NA, "630.00900000000001", "630.02599999999995", "9910.6610000000001", 
NA, "2.4E-2", "6.8000000000000005E-2", "0.125"), `2008` = c(NA, 
NA, "1920.6969999999999", "298.24900000000002", "9.5000000000254659E-2", 
"2219.0410000000002", "11558.616", NA, "1427.2470000000001", 
"298.24900000000002", "1725.4970000000001", "2268.846", NA, "466.66800000000001", 
"466.66800000000001", "9289.7669999999998", NA, "8.0000000000000002E-3", 
"8.0000000000000002E-3", "3.0000000000000001E-3"), `2009` = c(NA, 
NA, "1244.5440000000001", "380.97300000000001", "9.1999999999870852E-2", 
"1625.6089999999999", "8349.9950000000008", NA, "931.88599999999997", 
"380.97300000000001", "1312.8589999999999", "2018.4580000000001", 
NA, "285.524", "285.524", "6331.5370000000003", NA, "0", "0", 
"0"), `2010` = c(NA, NA, "1444.7629999999999", "522.22799999999995", 
"0.27199999999993452", "1967.2629999999999", "7997.5940000000001", 
NA, "1068.0989999999999", "522.22799999999995", "1590.329", "2298.473", 
NA, "349.59300000000002", "349.608", "5697.6090000000004", NA, 
"7.4999999999999997E-2", "0.14099999999999999", "1.512"), `2011` = c(NA, 
NA, "1227.779", "616.80200000000002", "5.4000000000087311E-2", 
"1844.635", "7872.6840000000002", NA, "847.86699999999996", "616.80200000000002", 
"1464.6679999999999", "2115.116", NA, "347.83800000000002", "347.83800000000002", 
"5748.56", NA, "1.181", "1.181", "9.0079999999999991"), `2012` = c(NA, 
NA, "1432.0730000000001", "716.904", "0.10400000000004184", "2149.0810000000001", 
"7909.7569999999996", NA, "1073.6510000000001", "716.904", "1790.5550000000001", 
"2291.1790000000001", NA, "316.58999999999997", "316.58999999999997", 
"5615.6930000000002", NA, "0.28399999999999997", "0.28399999999999997", 
"2.8849999999999998"), `2013` = c(NA, NA, "1640.125", "508.33600000000001", 
"2.4999999999863576E-2", "2148.4859999999999", "6947.2889999999998", 
NA, "1282.3920000000001", "508.33600000000001", "1790.7260000000001", 
"2039.7719999999999", NA, "319.83699999999999", "319.83699999999999", 
"4904.0569999999998", NA, "0.34699999999999998", "0.34699999999999998", 
"3.46"), `2014` = c(NA, NA, "2207.404", "738.54499999999996", 
"1.6000000000076398E-2", "2945.9650000000001", "7232.5640000000003", 
NA, "1754.615", "738.54499999999996", "2493.1590000000001", "2355.2040000000002", 
NA, "410.31599999999997", "410.33300000000003", "4873.2960000000003", 
NA, "0.39900000000000002", "0.39900000000000002", "4.0640000000000001"
), `2015` = c(NA, NA, 1711.844, 881.67, 0.0969999999997526, 2593.611, 
7661.203, NA, 1340.707, 881.67, 2222.376, 1996.221, NA, 333.077, 
333.077, 5656.871, NA, 0.563, 0.578, 8.111), `2016` = c(NA, NA, 
1406.048, 584.568, 0.118999999999915, 1990.735, 7335.19, NA, 
1062.578, 584.568, 1647.147, 1715.476, NA, 295.494, 295.511, 
5598.491, NA, 1.638, 1.638, 21.223), `2017` = c(NA, NA, 1228.098, 
714.667, 0.112999999999829, 1942.878, 7365.575, NA, 859.42, 714.667, 
1574.087, 1815.707, NA, 325.954, 325.994, 5540.777, NA, 0.497, 
0.524, 9.091)), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Use `lapply` instead of `sapply`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may use `lapply` instead of `sapply` as sapply returns a `matrix` and this can have only a single class i.e. if there is any column that is a character, it can result in `character`

```
animals[3:18] <- lapply(animals[3:18], as.numeric)
```

Or more easily

```
animals <- type.convert(animals, as.is = TRUE)
```

Or with `dplyr`, use `across` to loop over the columns

```
library(dplyr)
animals <- animals %>%
     mutate(across(3:18, as.numeric))
```

Or dynamically

```
animals <- animals %>% 
   mutate(across(c(where(is.character), -matches("^\\D+")), as.numeric))
```

-output

```
> str(animals)
tibble [20 × 21] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
 $ Class : chr [1:20] NA "Total live animals 1/" NA NA ...
 $ Source: chr [1:20] NA NA "CANADA" "MEXICO" ...
 $ 1999  : num [1:20] NA NA 876.869 292.158 0.148 ...
 $ 2000  : num [1:20] NA NA 995.945 405.311 0.076 ...
 $ 2001  : num [1:20] NA NA 1343.479 407.901 0.027 ...
 $ 2002  : num [1:20] NA NA 1394.815 300.496 0.399 ...
 $ 2003  : num [1:20] NA NA 784.265 469.926 0.177 ...
 $ 2004  : num [1:20] NA NA 560.141 540.997 0.529 ...
 $ 2005  : num [1:20] NA NA 1134.89 515.452 0.296 ...
 $ 2006  : num [1:20] NA NA 1616.48 524.25 0.32 ...
 $ 2007  : num [1:20] NA NA 2069.158 475.42 0.111 ...
 $ 2008  : num [1:20] NA NA 1920.697 298.249 0.095 ...
 $ 2009  : num [1:20] NA NA 1244.544 380.973 0.092 ...
 $ 2010  : num [1:20] NA NA 1444.763 522.228 0.272 ...
 $ 2011  : num [1:20] NA NA 1227.779 616.802 0.054 ...
 $ 2012  : num [1:20] NA NA 1432.073 716.904 0.104 ...
 $ 2013  : num [1:20] NA NA 1640.125 508.336 0.025 ...
 $ 2014  : num [1:20] NA NA 2207.404 738.545 0.016 ...
 $ 2015  : num [1:20] NA NA 1711.844 881.67 0.097 ...
 $ 2016  : num [1:20] NA NA 1406.048 584.568 0.119 ...
 $ 2017  : num [1:20] NA NA 1228.098 714.667 0.113 ...
```

Comment: Thanks very much, I tried both of your ideas but it's still same result.

Comment: I added the dput and viewed it to have an idea of the operation, so I found that there are other records on the same role with the exponential, but they all changed at the run of my command other than the two columns of 2013 and 2014.

Comment: Thanks very much for the support @akrun , and apologies for any inconveniences so far.  I just ran the `dput(head(animals, 20))` as you said, and the result is too big for this comment section.  I'm new to this platform and this is my first project. hoping to hear back from you

Comment: @FASASIKamorudeen you don't need to post on the comment.  Just edit your post and paste it there.  It is just for others to test your data

Comment: @FASASIKamorudeen please note that `animals[3:16]` only include columns till 2012, thus it is not converting to numeric for 2013 and 2014

Comment: @FASASIKamorudeen you can check the update

Comment: Thanks very much @akrun , I've realized my mistake and all methods work perfectly. Thanks once again.

Comment: @FASASIKamorudeen i would say that using column indexes should be careful as this can be buggy when you do some transformations by adding new columns etc.

Comment: Noted with thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to combine with `format` function.

For instance,

```
as.numeric("12389054328902")
"1.238905e+13"
format(as.numeric("12389054328902"), scientific = F)
"12389054328902"
```